# Careers 2.0 keeps linking my project to the favicon

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I've added a project on my Careers.SO and the tool automatically added an icon from the project's website's favicon.ico.

However it also added a link, and the link points to the favicon not the original website.

Any ideas how to fix this? I don't have an edit field for the URL anymore.

Answer (score 3):

This was a problem on our end having to do with the canonical meta tag. The best thing to do is either delete and re-add the project, or email us at careers@stackoverflow.com and we'll correct it manually for you.